# How to set a title if URL contains exactly URL, and nothing after it?

Tags: php

I am currently using:

```
 if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/administrator/index.php?option=com_ohanah&view=event") !== false){
            $this->getCommand('title')->title = $translator->translate('test');
        }
```

but this sets the `title` for all URLs even if it contains something after the `&view=event`. How can I do this only on the exactly URL?

Comment: This question is lacking details. Can you give examples, and preferably some working code?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware a working code is not possible because this only works with the Joomlatools Framework. The Code below the if needs to be applied if the URL exactly contains the URL given in my example. But my example applies also if it contains` ?nasdkfna` after the URL, and this is what I need to prevent.

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/administrator/index.php?option=com_ohanah&view=event"){//set title}` ??

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, well try what rtfm wrote.

Comment: @rtfm not working :/

Comment: Never say 'not working' always say explicitly what happens when.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will have the full (`http://example.com` ...)uri, you will need to add it to the string

Comment: @rtfm well ... I just had to remove the `!` so it is now `==` instead of `!==`

Comment: well no one told you to leave that in, its not in my code

Comment: REQUEST_URI does not have the full uri.

Comment: @Evert ok, didn't check, my bad